# Obligar a un archivo TXT que sea ANSI o UTF con PHP

Tags: php, archivo, txt

Estoy haciendo un proyecto donde hay un radio button que tiene 2 opciones:
Cotejamiento utf8
Cotejamiento Ansi

Al elegir una de las 2 se descarga el archivo pero cuando voy al notepad++ a verificar con que cotejamiento queda siempre marca utf8 por mas que marque Ansi

El codigo es un simple fopen

Alguna idea de como forzar cotejamientos en php?
Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

La función **iconv** te puede ayudar a pasar de una codificación a otra de un string y ese string convertido lo grabas en tu archivo.

[Aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.iconv.php) esta la documentación de PHP.

Te dejo un ejemplo simple:

```
$miArchivo= fopen("archivo.txt","w");

$cadenaConvertida = iconv('UTF-8', 'Windows-1252', $miCadena); // Codificación inicial, Codificación final, Cadena a convertir.

fwrite($miArchivo, $cadenaConvertida );

fclose($miArchivo);
```

Es importante que si grabas disitintas lineas, es necesario que todas tengan la misma codificación.